# Connecting from gatling simulation inside Docker to localhost

Tags: docker, localhost, gatling, connection-refused

I am trying to test my localhost service using Gatling inside Docker using MacOS.

I run Docker using:

```
  docker run -it -d --rm \
    --network="host" \
    -v $(PWD)/conf:/opt/gatling/conf \
    -v $(PWD)/user-files:/opt/gatling/user-files \
    -v $(PWD)/results:/opt/gatling/results \
    --name $CONTAINER_NAME $IMAGE_NAME
```

Afaik using '--host' enables using host network from inside Docker.

My service runs o port 9000, so my base url in Gatling, so I define it like that:

```
  private val baseUrl = "http://127.0.0.1:9000"
  private val httpProtocol = http
    .baseUrl(baseUrl)
```

Although I keep getting:

```
AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: /127.0.0.1:9000
```

Is there an issue with my config, or Gatling limitation?

Comment: Which OS you are using? Mac or Windows?

Comment: I use macOS, I will add it to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the host address from `http://127.0.0.1` to `host.docker.internal` and it should work.

In essence `host.docker.internal` will returns the IP for our docker host. But this feature only exists in Docker for Mac OSX & Docker for Windows. You could read more about this feature here:

> https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/networking/
>
> https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/networking/.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to connect to the service. I guess using linux I would have to pass local IP explicitly to achieve same results?

Comment: Can you please accept the answer and close the question?